# Save order without sending the invoice / order details woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to create manual orders for the customers in the woocommere --> orders section and send them the link for payments.

The issue is that when i create the order, there is no option to save it. The order action requires the email confirmation to be sent to the user for me to save the order.

I have disabled the email notification from Woocommerce --> Settings --> emails --> Processing order but the "Customer invoice/ order details" don't have an option to remove the notification.

I want to find a way where I can save the order but not send the email to the customer (instead i will send them a custom email with the order payment link)

any ideas?

Comment: WooCommerce dev support and 3rd party plugin/theme dev support are off topic on this stack, and not in our scope. This is not a place to get help with WooCommerce. You should go to the official support routes or ask in a WooCommerce community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't go in code details, but I would consider two different strategies among many others:

- using a custom query using [WPDB class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/), based on WooCommerce queries;
- unhook all undesired [filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/) and [actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) from WordPress, WooCommerce and other plugins.

I would probably start with the second one.